# Scrape Facebook with Goutte and Symfony2 - Login Cookies Error

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, curl, goutte

I am using `symfony2` and `Goutte` to scrape web data. I'm trying to simply login to facebook and return logged in page data.

Here's my code:

```
<?php


namespace junk\scraperBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Goutte\Client;


class ThingController extends Controller
{
public function somethingAction($something)
{

    // make a request to an external site
    $client = new Client();
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE); 
    $client->setHeader('User-Agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36");
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.facebook.com');

    // select the form and fill in some values
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Log In')->form();
    $form['email'] = 'email@junk.com';
    $form['pass'] = 'password';

    // submit that form
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
    echo $crawler->html();

    return $this->render('scraperBundle:Thing:index.html.twig');

}



} // END class ThingController
```

The thing is that I get an error:

`Cookies Required 
Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue.`

I'm thinking the problem is in my configuration options for `cURL`. With only the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` options I was able to successfully get into other `https` pages like GitHub, but I just can't figure out how to do that for Facebook.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Facebook does not want you to login using such automated tools, and that’s why they have taken extensive measures against this. If you want to interact with Facebook – use their API.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by this way:

```
public function somethingAction($something)
{
    $cookie_file = '/tmp/' . uniqid() . 'cookie';

    $client = new Client();

    /.../

    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file); 
    $client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file); 

    /.../
}
```

Hope it can help you.